# Remove everything after 1st opening bracket incl. the opening bracket - in a string - PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, variables, brackets

I am pulling location off an API.

The variable $location sometimes contains:

1. Paris
2. New York (Manhattan)

Paris is OK.

I only want the city name. So, New York (Manhattan) should be New York.

How do I remove everything after the 1st bracket (and including the 1st bracket) in variable $location?

And will the code that does that affect the content of $location if it only contains 1 word (e.g. Paris)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex like below and use an empty replacement string:

```
\(.*
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/rW4qN3/1)**

```
$re = "/\\(.*/"; 
$str = "Paris New York (Manhattan)\n\nParis is OK. I only want the city name. So, New York (Manhattan) should be New York.\n"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, "", $str);
```

Check the substitution panel below:

[image]

Comment: This worked for me. I then used rtrim to remove the extra space it left (from the space between the word and the bracket). Awesome. Thx.

Comment: @CodyRaspien glad to help. Btw, you can also use `$re = "/\\s*\\(.*/";` to remove the blanks too.

Answer (score 2):

```
$pos = strpos($location, "(");

if ($pos) $location = substr($location, 0, $pos);
```

What about this?

Comment: And why not  `$location = trim(explode('(', $location)[0]);`? In this way you don't need to test anything.